# Calling overloaded function from within another function with parent class argument

Tags: c++

I am trying to find a way to make something similar to this work:

```
class A {
public:
  int x;
};

class A1 : public A {
public: 
  int y;
};

class A2 : public A {
public:
  std::string s;
};

void printer(A1 A1obj){
  std::cout << (A1obj.y+1) << std::endl;
}

void printer(A2 A2obj){
  std::cout << A2obj.s << std::endl;
}

void printall(A Aobj){
  printer(Aobj);
}
```

In words: I have some code that works with `A` objects. many functions in my code take A objects as arguments, making no use of the `y` or `s` components. however eventually they will call a couple of functions that will behave differently according to whether the input A was really A1 or A2. I was thinking that I could "overload" these, considering both A1 and A2 are children of A. But the above code says *no matching function for call to `printer(A&)`*

One solution is to duplicate `printall` into `printall(A1 A1obj)` and `printall(A2 A2obj)` and use function overloading, but this would mean duplication of a many lines of code in my case, so I'd like to avoid it. Are there alternatives other than just merging `A1` and `A2` into `A` and, say, create a `std::string label` inside it to be used with if-else statements?

Comment: Why can't void printer() be a member function of A and overridden in A1 and A2?  It makes the problem trivial.

Comment: well yes, in this case it is trivial, but the actual problem I'm considering would require substantial additional work to do this kind of change (which I agree would make the code better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Virtual functions ("run-time polymorphism")

Whatever makes sense as a conceptual thing to do with/to an `A`, but the details of what that means will vary by specific class, should be a virtual function of `A`.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() = default;
  // Disable copying to avoid accidental slicing:
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

  virtual void print() const = 0;

  int x;
};

class A1 : public A {
public: 
  void print() const override;
  int y;
};
class A2 : public A {
public:
  void print() const override;
  std::string s;
};

void A1::print() const {
  std::cout << y+1 << std::endl;
}
void A2::print() const {
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

void printall(const A& Aobj) {
  Aobj.print();
}
```

Each derived class `A1` and `A2` overrides the virtual function declared in `A`, so calling the function via an `A` reference or pointer will actually call the definition from the derived class.

Option 2: A template function ("compile-time polymorphism")

```
// Classes and printer overloads as in question

template <class T>
void printall(const T& Aobj) {
  printer(Aobj);
}
```

Define a template function which can take an object of any type, and generates a function for that type as needed. Here `T` could really be anything at all, not necessarily a class which inherits `A`, as long as it can be passed to some `printer` function.

But if there are other `printall` functions and that declaration makes it too greedy in overload resolution, you can restrict it to only take types that inherit `A`.

If you can use C++20 "constraints and concepts":

```
#include <concepts>

template <class T> requires std::derived_from<T, A>
void printall(const T& Aobj) {
  printer(Aobj);
}
```

Otherwise, you'd need something a little trickier:

```
// C++11 or later:
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type
printall(const T& Aobj) {
  printer(Aobj);
}
```

Comment: I went for the "quick & dirty" change with templates. worked great and saved me some time. will go back to using option 1 at a later stage. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ambiguous overloading. Even if there was only one printer() function, and one child class, this will never work. If you have a parent class, `A`, it cannot be implicitly converted to any child class, like `A1`. You can implicitly convert a child class to a parent class, but not the other way around. This is the only way C++ works.

The correct way is to define an abstract `print()` method in the `A` superclass, and then implement it in both `A1` and `A2` subclasses, to invoke the appropriate `printer()` function. This is precisely why virtual methods exist. Or, just implement each `printer()` in the subclass directly, as a `print()` method.

Comment: thank you, I'll end up doing something like this at some point. unfortunately I'm merging 2 branches of my code both of which were using source I imported from elsewhere, so it will take a while.